# iOS / Xcode - Picking files from Dropbox and transferring to a Public Server

Tags: ios, xcode, dropbox

I need to develop an App in which the user can pick files from their Dropbox account and initiate a transfer a Public / Crowd sourced server.

This is not a migration of cloud storage, but manually selecting files and transferring them to a server. I have seen apps which help in migration of cloud storage through an automated script. As this is not a migration, the user may not understand what he is actually doing, or the implications of it.

My question is:

- Will Apple reject the app when uploaded to the App Store for such an operation?
- Will this be violating User privacy, as the user might unintentionally transfer sensitive information to a public cloud / server?

Diagrammatic representation of the operation:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per Apple's guidelines

> 17.1 Apps cannot transmit data about a user without obtaining the user's prior permission and providing the user with access to
>   information about how and where the data will be used

So basically, to answer your question

1. You should provide proper message to the user of what exactly your app intends to do. Lets say in the form of a **cancellable alert.
   Without this apple will surely reject your app**.
2. Secondly, this
   should **not be the necessary condition** for your app to work. Meaning
   that your app should work even if the user denies to share his
   images and stuff from dropbox.
3. Prior to sharing / uploading user should get **a view of what is being shared. Without this the application will be rejected**. (This is even applicable even in the simple facebook share)

You always have a quick look on the [Apple's privacy policies](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#privacy) here